# Stroke order for interpolation?

Tags: grease-pencil, 2d, interpolation

New to blender, so advice is appreciated! I’m in a 2D project and working on a complex shape - namely a hand - and am trying to interpolate it into another pose. However, things turn out wonky during the interpolation because some of my lines are out of order or were made in the wrong direction.

I know that in most tween-capable animation softwares there’s a guide to stroke order and direction. Arrange strokes doesn’t seem capable of this, and I’m not yet aware of a function that is. Does Blender 2.9 have a way of guiding or changing stroke order/direction to better accommodate interpolating?

Answer (score 0):

So I did some digging on this topic and found the answer. As future reference for 2D animators coming into Blender like me, stroke order for interpolation is the same as stroke order for stacking purposes. I do not believe there is a guide for stroke order because it was designed under a different concept - to be able to restack strokes like one would with layers. Stroke order is designed to be able to reorganize a layer, not aid in interpolation.

While this could be a bit of a setback, it also means that you are able to pick and choose which strokes are interpolated into others via the stacking order. Bringing a stroke to the front or back of a drawing will automatically sync it with the strokes on other frames.

Comment: from 2.93 beta we can select a pair of strokes to be interpolated: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=88FsF6ontPk

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for! Can’t wait for end of may!

Comment: and you don't have to ;) https://builder.blender.org/download/